# Laguerre's Method

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods

Given that,

polynomial $P(z) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} a_i z^i$

where $a_i$ are the real coefficients and $P(z_0) = 0$.

With the help of Laguerre's Method we find the rest of the complex solutions of the polynomials. But how do we prove $P(\bar z_0) = 0$ ??

I mean how can we show that the complex conjugate of the $z_0$ is also a solution to the Polynomial $P(z)$??

Answer (score 3):

Using the fact $\overline{ab} = \bar{a}\bar{b}$, you can see (via induction) that $\bar {z}^n = \overline{z^n}$. Combine it with the fact that $\overline{a+b} = \bar{a} + \bar{b}$ and that the coefficients are real so $\bar{a_i}=a_i$ to get,
$$ P(\bar{z_0}) = \overline{P(z_0)}=  \bar 0 = 0$$

Answer (score 3):

Roots to polynomials with real coefficients must either be real or come in complex conjugate pairs, because if they don't, then the product $a_n\prod_k^n(z-z_k)$ - which expands to the polynomial $P$ will generate some coefficient that is not real.

Comment: I get your point of argument, but is there like "formal" way to prove it?

Comment: You can take a look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem is another maybe more "formal" way. That proof seems to be the same principle as Harsh presents.